# Running ASP on Windows 2008 Server with COM DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, iis-7

I have a Windows Server 2008 Standard 64-bit box on which I run a test web site under IIS7. 
My hosting provider has the same configuration than me *yet* my precious custom DLL is not honored?
Calls to my DLL (plain vanilla _CDECL Export Functions) are, well. "ignored".
No error message. Nothing. Zilch. I press the button in the middle of the page that should trigger the calls but nothing happens.

The DLL is located in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 on both machines.
That's the path used in my DllImport declaration.

The site is setup with ASP.NET v4 with Integrated Pipeline mode.

I checked for pesky dependencies and this DLL makes calls to Kernel32.dll and NTdll.dll, both of which who are sitting in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 next to my dear DLL.

No, I didn't have to register this DLL on my machine.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You are giving contradictory statements here for the reader. Subject line of the question indicated you are referring to a classic ASP application with COM components (which needs to be registered globally unless you've used registration-free COM). But, your question and tags indicate it's an ASP.Net application with common class libraries used by that application (which doesn't need to be registered). So, give more details of your question.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help and patience. I should have written "ASP.NET" in the subject line. I appologize for my technical ignorance in advance. I since found out my hosting provider runs Windows Server 2008 R2. I upgraded my server accordingly. Still, no luck. My DLL is strictly a bunch of ANSI C exported functions that I call in my C# code behind through interop DLLImport Attributes. The thing is, I have no clue why this DLL can't be found accross different environments and I admit I am running out of ideas.

Comment: That's more like it Roger. So, you are using a COM DLL with Interop. This is how we call methods within a COM component in .Net. First you need to register your COM DLL using regsvr32.exe. You cannot register Interop DLLs so just keep it in the bin directory or in GAC.

Comment: I tried the bin directory but it never worked. As far as I know, the bin directory is only meant to work for "managed" DLLs. As far as registering the DLL, using regsvr32.exe, that does not work. It comes down to this, does the DLL need to be registered *in order* for it to work? And the answer seems to be no? In my case, on my Win2k8R2 Server, the DLL is *not* registered.

Comment: No, I asked you to register the COM DLL that's being called by your Interop DLL indirectly. You can't register Interop DLLs and it must reside in the bin. And, your COM doesn't need to be in bin. Just unregister the COM from your local machine using the same command to whether your app still works

Comment: The COM DLL is not registered on my local machine?

Comment: Where is it located?

Comment: C:\Windows\SysWOW64. My DLL Attribute statement is :
[DllImport("C:\Windows\System32\my.dll", PreserveSig = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]

Comment: Ok, the path C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and the attribute DllImport suggest that you are referring to the managed Interop DLL. I'm more interested in the unmanaged DLL mentioned in DllImport "C:\Windows\System32\my.dll". Is this my.dll registered? Can you check that by creating a sample VbScript file (.vbs) with Set test = Server.CreateObject("MyClass"). Replace MyClass with a class name within this DLL. Once saved double click on the file and see whether you are getting any errors.

Comment: And, one more thing. Can you check what's the application pool identity is in you production server? If it's not "ApplicationPoolIdentity" can you change it to that and see whether you could open the website. Sometimes there are permission issues to these system folders so that the framework cannot instantiate DLLs located there.

Comment: Sam, "my.DLL" is not registered. I'll try your VbScript suggestion. The site is not running Under ApplicationPoolIdentity, just .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: Ok, what did you mean by "just .NET Framework 4.0"? Can you run it under ApplicationPoolIdentity?

Comment: Would that make a difference? I think I already tried that. Please don't be offended by my ignorance.

Comment: No issues Roger. Have a try with that. Because you may not have permissions to these system folders with other options. And, how did you go with the vb script?

Comment: The permission is IIS7 permission, right? If that's the case, I am surprised that on this Win2k8R2 installation, this IIS7 *has* permission to the directory, yet at my hosting provider, on their Win2K8R2 installation, their IIS7 does (not) have permission on the same directory. I admit I am not knowledgeable enough to tell :(

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Did you try the vbScript thing? And, I think you should post this question in http://superuser.com/ where there are lot of experienced people who are doing these admin stuff.